# Are backslashes at the end of folder paths relevant?

Tags: c#, filepath

I am writing a program that copies all files and directories from a source location into a target location. Both locations are provided by the user.

I was just thinking about checking whether the location paths have a backslash "\" at the end, when I decided to run some tests and from what I see it doesn't matter if you tell c#

```
File.Copy("C:\\test", "D:\\test")`
```

or

```
File.Copy("C:\\test\\", "D:\\test\\")`
```

Am I wrong? Does a backslash at the end of a file path matter?

Comment: Try it out......

Comment: @gunr2171, from the question text it sounds like the OP did try it out and is just looking for confirmation.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, unless you attempt to do something with string itself, e.g. manually combine the pathes/files (don't, use `Path.Combine`) or trying to distinguish between folder and file ([`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `""` only for `"c:\\test\\"`)...

Comment: Since `File.Copy` expects _filenames_ and not paths as it's arguments, your code will not execute successfully unles you have a file named `test` in the root folder of drive C.  In any event, you should use `Path.Combine` when building file paths and the slashes will be handled for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should make no difference, because - on windows - you cannot have a folder "test" and file named "test" without extension in the same parent directory at the same time.

However, it will be much more cleaner to have a trailing backslash within your code, because this leaves no room for speculation. And it will be better for cross-plattform purposes as well.

Thinking of URIs for example, it can definitely make a difference between a trailing slash or no trailing slash, by the way.

TLDR: Use a trailing (back)slash, please :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

On Windows, you apparently cannot name a file and folder the same, so it won't matter there. You should still use a (back)slash for good style and cross-platform compatability. Some software or libraries might even depend on it.

**Original Answer:**

A folder is generally ending in `\` (or `/`), because there might be a file with no extension, named `test`. For example, these two could coexist (Linux [notice the different capitalization]):

Folder: `/Users/nikxda/Docouments/Test/`
File: `/Users/nikxda/Docouments/test`

If you work case-sensitive, then you could in fact ignore it on Windows. I'd still recommend using a trailing slash, just for

- Clarification (specify it is a folder)
- Good style (following conventions)
- Compatibility (other software, libraries, etc. might depend on it)
- Cross platform (OSX, ...)

So yes, you should always use a (back)slash at the end of your path if referring to folders.

Comment: In windows you can't have a file and folder named the same thing.

Comment: Then, you should still consider this approach, because it will be cross-platform compatible.

Comment: Well on unix you also cannot have folder and file with the same name. I wonder if there are actually any platforms where you can do this.

Comment: You can, if you change capitalization of the names. I do not know what windows does in this case. If you take this into consideration, and the fact that folders on linux are in fact special files - there is no difference. I find this to be important however.

Comment: Changing capitalization does not make a difference on windows, I think, but it does on *nix-systems.

Comment: @iquellis, you are correct - Windows is case insensitive, so capitalization makes no difference. You cannot have a folder and a file in the same directory with the same, regardless of case.